# How to get URL by route name in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I Know we can create links using component name `router-link :to="{ name: route.name }"`

But how can I get the route URL by name? or even the full route object using name?

assuming I have this routes below

```js
{ 
    path: "/join/parent", 
    name: "join.parent", 
    component: page("guest/join.vue") 
}
```

How can I get `http://base.url/join/parent` using the `join.name` or even better, how can I get the full object route

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-resolve

Comment: cool, ```resolve``` is what I was looking for, ```const route = this.$router.resolve({name: 'apply'})``` then ```route.href```